# Wake lock required for BroadcastReceiver while phone sleeps?

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-wake-lock

Trying to write a Broadcast Receiver that processes incoming SMSs. Do I need to use a wake lock / partial wake lock, for this application to work, in spite of device going to sleep due to lack of foreground activity ?

Answer (score 1):

I tend to extend a WakefulBroadcastReceiver to simplify things, so in a way yes. For example:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        final ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                MyIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. While I do understand the BroadcastReceiver based implementation, the 'WakefulBroadcastReceiver' is very new to me. At the outset, it looks like a great simplification (compared to code I'd have to write to acquire and release the partial wake-lock), but I was wondering if there was a way to avoid using a Service !